# Electric field outside a standing electron wave

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics

If an electron were confined in a cavity with perfectly reflecting ends, its wave function would form a standing wave in the cavity.  Presumably the electron would not emit EM radiation unless it were perturbed.

I imagine that if the electric field were measured outside the box, and if experiment were done many times and the results averaged, the averaged field would *not* be that of a point charge, but would instead be that of a charge distributed according to the squared amplitude of the wave function.

It seems obvious that if there were just one electron in the box, it would be very difficult if not impossible to measure the electric field without disturbing the electron.  The exclusion principle would prevent us from putting a lot of electrons into the box, all having the same wave function.  But if the electrons were replaced by Cooper pairs in a box comprising a length of superconducting wire, we could (presumably) have a large enough number of charge pairs in the same state to be able to measure the resulting distribution of charge.

Is it possible in principle to measure the electric field outside the box without perturbing the electron?  I suspect it's not possible, but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Since the electron can only be in a finite region of space, the x component of the field, $E_x$ can only take on certain values. We can find the expectation value by assuming the particle is at a specific location in the box, calculate the associated $E_x$ and multiply it by the probability that the particle is actually in that position. Sum this over all possible positions. 

But since the E field is measured by its effect on a charge and a charge generates a field, I'd think any measurement distorts.

Comment: The electron wave function can only have a very specific set of possible states. I think the question may be equivalent to asking whether it's possible to measure which state the electron is in without altering its state.

Comment: Can the field be measured without interference classically? Perhaps to some margin of error.